# Need help in identifying the difference between ESAPI.validator() and ESAPI.encoder()

Tags: esapi

We are implementing application security in our website. Its a REST based application, so i will have to validate the whole request payload, rather than each attribute. This payload need to be validated against all type of attacks (SQL,XSS etc). While browsing i found people are using ESAPI for web security.

I am confused between  `ESAPI.validator().getValidXXX`, `ESAPI.encoder()` Java API's of ESAPI library. What is the difference between these two and when to use which API. I would also like to know in what cases we might use both API's

As per my understanding i could encode an input to form a valid html using both API's
Eg:

1. `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(input);`
2. `ESAPI.validator().getValidSafeHTML(context, input, maxLength, allowNull)`.

For XSS attacks, I have made code changes to strip-of html tags using java pettern&matcher, but i would like to achieve the same using ESAPI. Can someone help me how to achieve it.

Or

Are there any new java plugins developed for websecurity similar to ESAPI which i did not come accross. I have found https://jsoup.org/, but it solves only XSS attacks, i am looking for a library which provides API's for several attacks (SQL injection/XSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(input);
```

You use this when you're sending input to a browser, so that the data you're sending gets escaped for HTML.  This can get tricky, because you have to know if that exact data is for example, being passed to javascript before it is being rendered into HTML.  Or if it's being used as part of an HTML attribute.

We use:

```
ESAPI.validator().getValidSafeHTML(context, input, maxLength, allowNull).
```

when we want to get "safe" HTML from a client, that is backed by an antisamy policy file that describes exactly what kinds of HTML tags and HTML attributes we will accept from the user.  The default is deny, so you have to explicitly tell policy file, if you will accept:

```
<a href="www.someurl.com">text</a>
```

You need to specify that you want the "a" tag, and that you will allow an "href" attribute, and you can even specify further rules against the content within the text fields and tag attributes.

You only need "getValidSafeHTML" if your application needs to accept HTML content from the user... which is usually specious in most corporate applications.  (Myspace used to allow this, and the result was the Samy worm.)

Generally, you use the validator API when content is coming into your application, and the encoder API when you direct content back to a user or a backend interpreter.  AntiSamy isn't supported anymore, so if you need a "safe HTML" solution, use OWASP's [HTML Sanitizer.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project)

> Are there any new java plugins developed for websecurity similar to
>   ESAPI which i did not come accross. I have found https://jsoup.org/,
>   but it solves only XSS attacks, i am looking for a library which
>   provides API's for several attacks (SQL injection/XSS)

The only other one that attempts a similar amount of security is HDIV.  Here is an [answer that compares HDIV to ESAPI by an HDIV developer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054803/557153)

*DISCLAIMER:  I am an ESAPI developer, and OWASP member.

Sidenote:  I discourage the use of Jsoup, because by default it mutates incoming data, constructing "best guess" (invalid) parse trees, and doesn't allow you fine-grained control of that behavior... meaning, if there's an instance where you want to override and mandate a particular kind of policy, [Jsoup asserts that it is always smarter than you are](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/411#issuecomment-90359602)... and that's simply not the case.